# Entity class not found when trying to create entities from yml config files

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create entity classes. I am using yml files from Resources/config/doctrine folder.

Category.orm.yml

```
Marek\JobeetBundle\Entity\Category:
  type: entity
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    name:
      type: string
      length: '255'
      unique: true
  manyToMany:
  affiliates:
    targetEntity: Marek\JobeetBundle\Entity\Affiliate
    joinTable:
      name: CategoryAffiliate
      joinColumns:
        category_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
      inverseJoinColumns:
        affiliate_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Affilate.orm.yml

```
Marek\JobeetBundle\Entity\Affiliate:
  type: entity
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    url:
      type: string
      length: '255'
      nullable: true
    email:
      type: string
      length: '255'
      nullable: true
      unique: true
    token:
      type: string
      length: '255'
    isActive:
      type: boolean
      nullable: false
      column: is_active
      default: 0
    createdAt:
      type: datetime
      column: created_at
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: create
  manyToMany:
  categories:
    targetEntity: Marek\JobeetBundle\Entity\Category
    mappedBy: affiliates
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Job:

```
Marek\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job:
  type: entity
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    type:
      type: string
      length: '255'
    company:
      type: string
      length: '255'
      nullable: true
    logo:
      type: string
      length: '255'
    url:
      type: string
      length: '255'
      nullable: true
    position:
      type: string
      length: '255'
      nullable: true
    location:
      type: string
      length: '255'
    description:
      type: string
      length: '4000'
    howToApply:
      type: string
      length: '4000'
      column: how_to_apply
    token:
      type: string
      length: '255'
      unique: true
    isPublic:
      type: boolean
      length: null
      column: is_public
    isActivated:
      type: boolean
      length: null
      column: is_activated
    email:
      type: string
      length: '255'
    createdAt:
      type: datetime
      column: created_at
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: create
    updatedAt:
      type: datetime
      column: updated_at
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: update
    expiresAt:
      type: datetime
      column: expires_at
  oneToOne:
    category:
      targetEntity: Marek\JobeetBundle\Entity\Category
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: null
      inversedBy: null
      joinColumns:
        category_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
      orphanRemoval: false
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

After executing:

> php app/console doctrine:generate:entities JobeetBundle --path="src"

I am getting:

> Warning: class_parent(): Class Marek\JobeetBundle\Entity\Affiliate
>   does not exists and could not be loaded in
>   vendor/gedmo-doctrine-extension\lib\Gedmo\Mapping\ExtensionMetadataFactory.php
>   on line 80.

I know that I have not any entities I want to create them.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be caused by an invalid assumption in Gedmo. Try commenting out the entire `stof_doctrine_extensions` block in your `config.yml` and then running the generate command. If it works, you should be able to uncomment the config and get back to work.